# Is this the correct xml regex for URL?

Tags: java, xml, regex, url-rewriting

I am implementing `urlReWriter` into my Java web project.

I want to change this url: `/read-post.jsp?id=1&title=some-cool-blog-title`

into this shortened/cleaner url: `/read-post/1/some-cool-blog-title`

This is the rule I have implemented:

```
<rule>
   <from>^/read-post/([0-9]+)/([0-9][a-z][A-Z]+)</from>
   <to>/read-post.jsp?id=$1&amp;title=$2</to>
</rule>
```

The problem is it isn't re writing the url and I suspect it is because the xml regex I've used is incorrect?

How do i format it correctly when there can be any number for the `id` and any number, character or special character `-` for the `title`?

Comment: apparently not according to the doc here: http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/guide.html. I agree it seems backwards though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression for the title `([0-9][a-z][A-Z]+)` is for sure not correct since the `+` refers to the `[A-Z]` only. In addition to this the `-` your are mentioning in the question is missing. You could try this instead: `([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)`

Comment: That worked thanks. For some reason however the linked page now doesn't apply styling like it did before. going CSS is applied fine `http://localhost:8080/site/read-post.jsp?id=1&title=some-cool-title-of-blo`, but not when the url is changed even though it is loading the same page.

Comment: Maybe this is because the stylesheet is loaded through a relative URL and with the _new_ URL this relative link is not correct any more.

Comment: How can i fix this without changing all relative URL's to their absolute URL?

Comment: Besides isn't it just loading the `http://localhost:8080/site/read-post.jsp?id=1&title=some-cool-title-of-blo` file underneath? Where relative url's should be valid?

Comment: Apparently you can specify a `base` `url` that will be used to load content relatively. Place it in the header section of relevent web page before any relatively linked sources. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE